# Reload page back to login angular 6

Tags: routes, guard, angular6

When I to do login I enter in dashboar ok, but when I reload the page its back to login I have guard routes if dont know is it, auth.guard.ts

```
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
if(this.service.authentication()) { 
  return true;
}
  this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  return false;
}
```

and my routes

```
...
{ path: 'painel', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'painel', loadChildren: 'app/administration/components/users/users.module#UsersModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AdministratorGuard] },
...
```

why when I to do login and I'll go to dashboard or any other page I refresh and its back to the login page ?